# Div Horizontal Scrollbar

Tags: html, scrollbar

I created a horizontal gallery for a client's website, which functions fairly well, not the best way for a gallery, but it's what they wanted:

http://www.lisagleeson.com/galleries/fashion/

It was done using the following code:

```
#galleryWrapper {
height: 525px;
width: 100%;
background-color: #ffffff;
padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
float: left;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow-y: hidden;
overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

They are reporting it's a little difficult to scroll these images left to right, part of this is because there is no scrollbar within the div. I need assistance on how to add that scrollbar without having to change over to using an iFrame..

Comment: So, what is the problem? I can see scrollbar on Windows machine. I think scrollbar is visible on Apple Mac too.

Comment: i've looked at Firefox, Chrome and Safari and the scrollbar is only visible after using the touchpad. Guess I'm thinking there should be something visible with do anything with the mouse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you can make "progress bar" which will display current scroll position, something like scrollbar. Listen for `scroll` event on slider and update progress bar position. If you're not planning 2-ways interaction (drag this progress bar and scroll slider), then JS code will be simple.

I can see only one problem here - progress bar design :) There are a lot of progress bar examples - scrollbar with track, simple scrollbar, paging with [radiobuttons](http://tinyurl.com/m4j3qzw), etc...

If you want to make scrollbar draggable, you can use [jQuery Scrollbar](http://github.com/gromo/jquery.scrollbar) which hides native scrollbar, but still allows scrolling with mouse/touch (not JS emulation!). Scrollbars are fully CSS customizable.